# Is there a "Dialer" program that comes with XP Pro and where is it?

Tags: windows-xp, voip

Is there a "Dialer" program that comes with XP Pro and where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, yes.

Install it, if you haven't already, by going to *Control Panel->Add/Remove Programs* and selecting *Install Windows Components* (or similar wording) from the left panel.

To run it, or check if you have it installed already, type dialer.exe in your Run... box.

Comment: Thank you. I am not yet set up to use it so I get a "server could not be found" message, but its there.